# using and/or extracting expandable files (obb) android

Tags: java, android, apk-expansion-files

I was able to upload an expandable file and download it
on my app from google play. Following the o`[fficial tutorial][1]`

It saved the obb file to /Android/Obb/main.2.myappname.obb

I assumed this obb file would be extracted on assets or raw folder or 
something similiar. The obb file was renamed after I zipped about 20 .mp3
files. They are named like so: 1.mp3, 2.mp3 etc.

Is it possible to extract the obb file if not how will I be able to 
access the invididual mp3 files, the way I am able to access them from
assets or raw folder. Let's say I want to access 1.mp3 which is present
on the .zip archive that was renamed to main.2.myappname.obb

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one has chimed in here.  You can use the StorageManager to mountObb(), unmountObb(), getMountedObbPath(), and isObbMounted().  After mounting an Obb and calling getMOuntedObbPath, you can use the path returned to do normal reads from it.  It acts as a virtual drive.  You just cannot write back to it.

Here's the link to the documentation:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html

Comment: what do i name the obb file if my app version is in the format 0.0.9 for instance? is it just 9? the integer equivalent?

Comment: The build number is usually an auto incremented number from your build system.  This is your best candidate.  So, 1.0.343 is your version NAME and 343 is your build number.

Comment: yes, i didn't realize the semantic version is uploaded, but a new build is issued by the Play Store for the actual build. The one issued by the server is the one you'd use.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the OBB directly via an `InputStream` using the `APK Expansion Zip Library`. Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files?hl=ko#ZipLib

Sample code:

```
try {
    String obbFilePath = mContext.getObbDir() + "/" + "main.{package_name}.{version_code}.obb";
    ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile(obbFilePath);
    InputStream inputStream = mExpansionFile.getInputStream("1.mp3");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Exception loading obb: " + e);
}
```

In place of the last line, since you are streaming a MP3, using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) is a better idea.